# Python-Generating numbers according to a corellation matrix

Tags: python, correlation

[image][image]

[image]

Hi, I am trying to generate correlated data as close to the first table as possible (first three rows shown out of a total of 13). The correlation matrix for the relevant columns is also shown (corr_total).

I am trying the following code, which shows the error:
"LinAlgError: 4-th leading minor not positive definite"

```
from scipy.linalg import cholesky

# Correlation matrix

# Compute the (upper) Cholesky decomposition matrix

upper_chol = cholesky(corr_total)

# What should be here? The mu and sigma of one row of a table?
rnd = np.random.normal(2.57, 0.78, size=(10,7))


# Finally, compute the inner product of upper_chol and rnd
ans = rnd @ upper_chol
```

My question is what goes into the values of The mu and sigma, and how to resolve the error shown above.
Thanks!
P.S I have edited the question to show the original table. It shows data for four patients. I basically want to make synthetic data for more cases, that replicates the patterns found in these patients

Comment: Do you have access to the mean and the covariance matrix of the data?

Comment: Hi, I just had the actual table of values (cropped for 3 rows and shown), and then i calculated the correlation matrix from that (also shown above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for answering my question about when data you have access to. The error that you received was generated when you called cholesky. cholesky requires that your matrix be positive semidefinite. One way to check if a matrix is semi-positive definite is to see if all of its eigenvalues are greater than zero. One of the eigenvalues of your correlation/covarance matrix is nearly zero. I think that cholesky is just being fussy. Use can use `scipy.linalg.sqrtm` as an alternate decomposition.

For your question on the generation of multivariate normals, the random normal that you generate should be a standard random normal, i.e. a mean of 0 and a width of 1. Numpy provides a standard random normal generator with `np.random.randn`.
To generate a multivariate normal, you should also take the decomposition of the covariance, not the correlation matrix. The following will generate a multivariate normal using an affine transformation, as in your question.

```
from scipy.linalg import cholesky, sqrtm
relavant_columns = ['Affecting homelife',
           'Affecting mobility',
           'Affecting social life/hobbies',
           'Affecting work',
           'Mood',
           'Pain Score',
           'Range of motion in Doc']

# df is a pandas dataframe containing the data frame from figure 1
mu = df[relavant_columns].mean().values
cov = df[relavant_columns].cov().values
number_of_sample = 10


# generate using affine transformation
#c2 = cholesky(cov).T
c2 = sqrtm(cov).T
s = np.matmul(c2, np.random.randn(c2.shape[0], number_of_sample)) + mu.reshape(-1, 1)

# transpose so each row is a sample
s = s.T
```

Numpy also has a built-in function which can generate multivariate normals directly

```
s = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=number_of_sample)
```

Comment: Hi alex, thanks so much for your answer, I used the correlation matrix because I saw it being used multiple times such as here: https://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2018/02/09/generation-of-correlated-random-numbers-using-python/

Comment: I have edited the question to show the whole table of original data, and its context. I'd love to hear your thoughts

Comment: @Ray92 I think that Cholesky was just being fussy. I updated my answer with a workaround. That article that you linked with generate correlated data, but it would not have the correct center or width.

Comment: Hi, so the following are the first two rows of the answer:                           array([[ 0.86314047,  1.47526447,  0.73896043,  0.86314047,  0.32524867,
         2.68821546,  1.56054772],
       [ 1.76109361, -0.14059524,  0.49934849,  1.76109359,  0.80724597,
         3.81200796,  1.76765357].                                                                      My question is that these numbers are not in the range of the numbers in the original table, (which are integer patient scores between 1 and 7), and also there are negative numbers in the array, which dont make sense in my case

Comment: I accepted the answer, thanks alex, but can you please elaborate on my comment above? Id be really grateful, thank you!

Comment: A multivariate normal distribution is used to model a set of continuous correlated variable. If you need to generate discrete variables over a finite support, it's not an appropriate distribution to use. I'm not sure what the proper distribution to model your data would be. The people over at stats.stackoverflow or math.stackoverflow would probably be able to make a suggestion.

Comment: I am in a situation where I am facing the same problem i.e., I define a covariance for which the cholesky decomposition fails. I need to generate some signals that would results in the desired covariance but cholesky seems to be out of the picture. Can you explain why using `sqrtm` is the same thing? It's the first time I am seeing this

Comment: If A has tiny eigenvalues, 0 to within machine precision,
about half of these "zeros" may be tiny negative, and `cholesky` complains. What to do: add e.g. 1e-6 to the diagonal, `corr += 1e-6 * np.eye( n )`. (This is a common problem; another cholesky program, [sksparse.cholmod](https://scikit-sparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cholmod.html) for large sparse matrices, has a parameter e.g. `beta=1e-6` to do this.)